# Calculating Density with igraph - why does igraph change the passed adjacency matrix?

Tags: r, igraph

I am having trouble getting igraph to calculate the density of an undirected network correctly.  My R code is below.

It is possible I am calculating density incorrectly, but I am confident I am not.  Instead, it appears that igraph will copy the 0s or 1s into their mirror cells, e.g. if node_i,j = 0 and node_j,i=1, then node_i,j becomes 1.  This behavior can be changed using the mode argument, but I do not see a way to have it *ONLY* count the values of the upper or low triangle.  For example, if node_i,j = 0 and node_j,i = 1, I want node_i,j to stay equal to 0.

```
set.seed(1234)


## Works for directed density
number <- 10
thismatrix <- matrix(rbinom(number^2, 1, .5), nrow=number)

## Calculate its directed density.
tm_d <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(thismatrix, mode='directed')
graph.density(tm_d)

# Works for directed
edges <- sum(thismatrix)
possibleedges <- nrow(thismatrix)*ncol(thismatrix)-nrow(thismatrix)
edges/possibleedges 

## Does not work for undirected density
tm_u <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(thismatrix, mode='undirected')
graph.density(tm_u)

temp2 <- thismatrix
temp2[lower.tri(temp2)] <- 0
diag(temp2) <- 0

edges <- sum(temp2)
possibleedges <- nrow(temp2)^2/2 - nrow(temp2)
edges/possibleedges

edges/possibleedges  == graph.density(tm_u)  # FALSE

# What does igraph see?
ugh <- as_adjacency_matrix(tm_u)  # It takes max(node_i,j, node_j,i)
ugh

## Using different modes does not solve it.
## none of the below calls to graph.density() generate what should be the correct density.
tm_u2 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(thismatrix, mode='undirected', diag=FALSE)
graph.density(tm_u2)

tm_u3 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(thismatrix, mode='upper')
graph.density(tm_u3)

tm_u4 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(thismatrix, mode=c('lower'))
graph.density(tm_u4)

tm_u5 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(thismatrix, mode=c('min'))
graph.density(tm_u5)
```